# Get the video id of the next video that plays?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I am using the Youtube API to play a video by it's videoId. This all works fine and the youtube video works:

```
var player = new YT.Player("videoplayer", {
  height: 400, 
  width: 600, 
  videoId: videoId, 
  events: {
    onReady: function (event) {
      event.target.playVideo();
    }
  }
});
```

When the video ends, Youtube will show thumbnails of recommended videos. Is it possible to get the videoId of the video that the user clicks on?

I was hoping that I could use the `onStateChange` method, but it doesn't look like there is a state to describe that the video that is being played as changed.

Is there a standard way to get the video id of the next Youtube video that a user picks?

Comment: never worked with youtube-api but can't you just add a clickhandler to the videolinks and get the video url by accessing `$(this).attr("url")` or `$(this).attr("href")` inside the handler?

Comment: @messerbill The youtube suggestions are in an iframe, so I can't attach events to them directly. There is also nothing in the Youtube IFrame API that points to be being able to detect clicks on these suggestions: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en#Events

Comment: it seems like `onStateChange` just notices, if the player is paused, playing or whatever. I also can't find anything like `onVideoChange` but you could try saving the actual video URL and check if the URL had changed after a `onStateChange` was fired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I looked into it. There is not exactly an event that fires when the user clicks the next video to watch, but the API will fire an `onApiChange` event.

So, you can check for a change in the video id, and the if there is a change, you run your callback:

```
var oldVideoId = 'abcd';
var checkIfVideoIdChanged = function(event) {
  var newVideoId = event.target.getVideoData().video_id

   if (newVideoId !== oldVideoId) {
     // Do your 'event' logic here
   }
};
var player = new YT.Player("videoplayer", {
  height: 400, 
  width: 600, 
  videoId: videoId, 
  events: {
    onReady: function (event) {
      event.target.playVideo();
    },
    onStateChange: function(event) {
      checkIfVideoIdChanged(event);
    },
    onApiChange: function(event) {
      checkIfVideoIdChanged(event);
    }
  }
});
```

EDIT: You should check both the onApiChange and onStateChange since sometimes the onApiChange does not get fired when the new video starts playing immediately.